# WebDriverWaitcauses the text extracted to be 'None' for 'td' elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

(using Selenium Webdriver on Python)

I have an explicit wait that I use to wait until an element is visible. Then extract the text from the element:

```
    def wait_and_get_text(self, locator, timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
    except TimeoutException:
        raise Exception(f"Presence of element {locator} was not detected after a timeout of {timeout}.")

    element_text = element.text
    return element_text
```

This function works except when I try to extract from a td element e.g. `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.username-td')` Then it returns the text as 'None'

If I remove the explicit wait and just type `self.driver.find_element("css selector", ".username-td").text` then the text does get extracted. But then I have no explicit wait. Does anyone know why this is the case with 'td' elements?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to extract from the text from the `<td>` element i.e.

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.username-td'
```

Then it returns the text as `None` as in the *`wait_and_get_text()`* method you are passing `timeout=None` by default which is later assigned to `timeout` and used within the [*WebDriverWait*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) as follows:

```
def wait_and_get_text(self, locator, timeout=None):
timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
```

So, though syntactically you have a [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) but functionally with a `timeout=None` the wait time is *`NULL`*.

Hence Selenium tries to extract the text immediately and subsequently prints `None`

---

### Solution

Supply a valid value as a `timeout`, as an example to set 5 seconds:

```
def wait_and_get_text(self, locator, timeout=5):
```